# Python: Copy files between two remote servers

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I want to understand the best way to copy files from one remote server to another remote server using python.

My setup looks something like this:

```
+--------------+
|   Server A   |                                                                              
+--------------+                                                                 
| Build Server |
+--------------+
       | 
       |
+-------------+
|  Server B   |
+-------------+
| Python Code |
+-------------+
      |
      |
+------------+
|  Server C  |
+------------+
| App Server |
+------------+
```

I have a few RPM's stored in the build server. These binaries needs to be transferred to the App server, so that i can install them on this box.

Currently i am using Python's Paramiko library [sftp.get and sftp.put] and get the binaries from Server A to Server B and transfer it to from Server B to Server C. Is there anyway i could structure my code so that the binaries can be transferred directly from Server A to Server C?

To be more precise, do something like this:

```
scp -3 user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
```

This kind of avoids the intermediate hop.

Suggestions/Improvements are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I would use `rsync` to handle this problem.</strike> You might be able to just directly call `scp` from Python using the `subprocess` module or try an existing Python module that wraps or implements `rsync`

It will be much easier to call `scp` via subprocess than perform all of the required operations via `paramiko`.

Comment: Unlike `scp`, rsync isn't capable of copying between two remote hosts.  You'd still need to `ssh` into one of the remote hosts to run the `rsync` command.  Though I agree that just using `subprocess` to call `scp` or `rsync` might be better than trying to find a python implementation of them.

Comment: would this do?`ssh user1@remote1 'rsync -avz /path/to/source user2@remote2:/path/to/dest'`